# 404 not found ! Why can't i write without extension?

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I am using ASP.NET and I am trying to make a link in my home page to Login page and Register page. I am getting the error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have this code :

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="~/Login" runat="server">Login</a></td>
    <br />
    <td><a href="~/Register" runat="server">Register</a></td>
</tr>
```

the page is there where I said it is.
but if I write this code, it works.

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="~/Login.aspx" runat="server">Login</a></td>
    <br />
    <td><a href="~/Register.aspx" runat="server">Register</a></td>
</tr>
```

Why can't I write without `.aspx` extension ?

I've seen enough examples where developers didn't write the extension.
What is the problem here? Why is this happening?

For example, here :
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation

```
<AnonymousTemplate>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you running this web page under IIS or asp.net development server?

Comment: I run this under IIS 8 .

Answer (score 0):

when u don't want to show the exyensions u have to use httphandlers to mask the url other wise .net compiler don't know how to compile the code

Comment: so how do i use these httphandlers ?